# Trying to make a post request to Shopify cart

Tags: jquery, shopify, shopify-api

First time trying this out. I want to add a product to customer's cart if they spend $200 or more. Not receiving anything in the response, wondering what I'm doing wrong. This code is inside checkout.liquid

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% assign found_title = false %}
    {% for item in checkout.line_items %}
      {% if item.variant.id == 6564672929928 %}
        {% assign found_title = true %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if checkout.subtotal_price > 20000 and found_title == false %}
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function () {
        variantId = 6564672929928
        jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
          items: [{
            quantity: 1,
            id: 6564672929928            
          }],
          function(res){
            console.log(res)
          }
        })
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the `res`?

Comment: It's showing up as undefined

Comment: Can you add.js accept a POST? Is it expecting an Array of Objects or just an Object? I also see you have a syntax issue, you ahve an Object with `items` but then you never close the Object. Check your Network details in the browser and see what the Response is, I suspect you're going to get an Error there or in your Server Log.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
$(function() {
  var variantId = 6564672929928;
  $.post('/cart/add.js', {
      items: [{
        quantity: 1,
        id: variantId
      }]
    },
    function(res) {
      console.log(res)
    }
  });
});
```

In your Data object, you failed to Close the Object:

```
jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
```

This Object that was started never was closed.